# Nuget install local package fails when referencing external package has metadata only (no lib)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget, self-host-webapi

I am trying to build a local package with Nuget.  My library uses several installed packages including "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost".  The OwinSelfHost package only has a .nupkg file and not a corresponding lib or content folders.  Nuget fails trying to find the .lib files that does not exist for that package.  Here is the call and the output:
nuget.exe install NCR.AS.MGC.ClientProxies -Source C:\Sandbox\MGC\Mgc.ClientProxies\bin\Debug -OutputDirectory C:\Sandbox\MGC\packages.out -ExcludeVersion -NoCache

Unable to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost'. Source(s) used: 'nuget.org', 'NugetServer'.
Feeds used:   C:\Sandbox\MGC\Mgc.ClientProxies\bin\Debug  Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'NCR.AS.MGC.ClientProxies.1.0.0' with respect to project 'C:\Sandbox\MGC\packages.out', targeting 'Any,Version=v0.0' Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'NCR.AS.MGC.ClientProxies.1.0.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'

Any suggestions on creating the local package?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out thanks to the help of a coworker that experienced this issue before.  The packages that were installed from the Nuget Package Manager where placed in c:\Sandbox\MGC\packages.  I was trying to build a local package that has my code which leverages some of the installed packages and have it write the local package in c:\Sandbox\MGC\packages.out.  If I write my output package in the same directory as my installed packages (c:\sandbox\MGC\packages) everything works without issue.  As soon as I try to put my stuff in a separate directory, it fails trying to find some of my installed packages.  To me, this seems to be a Nuget bug..

Comment: I'm not sure how you got it to output the package to the packages folder: I just manually copied mine into a folder and structured it to look like the other packages in the packages folder.